# Python : spectrogram speech recognition

Tags: python, signals, spectrogram

I am trying to reproduce a preprocessing seen in a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-sndkf7mCs where they create a spectrogram taking a windows of 20 ms and then apply an FFT on it. Finally they feed a neural network with the spectrogram obtained. I am using the scipy package but I am a little confused about the parameters to use. Here is the code :

```
def get_spectrogram(path, nsamples=16000):
    '''
    Given path, return specgram.
    '''
    # read the wav files
    wav = wavfile.read(path)[1] # 16000 samples per second

    # zero pad the shorter samples and cut off the long ones to have a signal of 1 sec.
    if wav.size < nsamples:
        d = np.pad(wav, (nsamples - wav.size, 0), mode='constant')
    else:
        d = wav[0:nsamples]

    # get the specgram
    specgram = signal.spectrogram(d, fs= ? , nperseg=None, noverlap=None, nfft=None)[2]

    return specgram
```

Moreover, I am also wondering what have to be the shape of the output ? Is it (X, 1) ?